# How can i use haskell to check if a list contains the values in a tuple

Tags: haskell

I am writing some functions for graphs in Haskell, and I want to check if a list of integers, such as

```
[1,4, 5, 7]
```

contains vertices that make an edge, which i have represented as a tuple, like so

```
(1,5)
```

Im trying to take a function that takes the list and the tuple, and in this case would return true, because the list contains a 1 and a 5. The main issue i am having is that im really not sure how to search a list in Haskell. Is their a function that takes a list of type [a] and a value of type a, and returns a Bool, depending on whether [a] contains a?

Comment: [Is their a function that takes a list of type \[a\] and a value of type a, and returns a Bool?](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a+-%3E+Bool)

Comment: their -> there, both in the post and in the pasted text for the link :)

Comment: How about `filter (==(1,5)) [(a,b)|a<-[1,4,5,7], b<-[1,4,5,7]]` which you can make into a function very easily.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a function to check whether a value is in a list,

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

Using that, your function is easily defined.

```
containsEdge :: [Int] -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
xs `containsEdge` (a,b) = (a `elem` xs) && (b `elem` xs)
```

Comment: You are missing the closing back-tick on `containsEdge`

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. You can correct such typos yourself, if you want. No reasonable person minds their typos being fixed, so don't be afraid.

Answer (score 12):

The elem function does that :

```
elem 1 [1,3,4]
```

will give True. Though this function is often used as an infix operator by surrounding it with backticks :

```
1 `elem` [1,4,5,7]
```

On the other hand, for big sets, that is not a very good idea (O(n) complexity), and you should use Set (or even IntSet if your elements are integers) instead of lists.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but what would constitute as a big set under the scope of Haskell? I'm new to the language.

Comment: I didn't benchmark so I can't be sure but anything over the tens would probably warrant a `Set`, especially since it's pretty easy to build and use a Set so why use the inferior alternative of lists ?