# What is the idiomatic Haskell way to check if one list contains all the values in another list?

Tags: list, haskell

My question is similar to [How can i use haskell to check if a list contains the values in a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9624655/10909834), but in my case, the list with values which must all be in my original list is the alphabet. It feels really messy to have 26 calls to `elem`, all ANDed together.

Is there any more concise way to check if a given list contains all of the elements in another list, where the other list is 26 items long?

Answer (score 3):

I like the answer by user1984, but it does leave implicit a bit the way you would handle non-alphabetic characters. Here's one that's almost as simple, but doesn't need extra code to handle non-alphabetic characters. The basic idea is to go the other direction; their answer builds up a set, this one tears one down by deleting one character at a time. It is also O(n), like theirs.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram = S.null . foldr S.delete (S.fromList ['a'..'z'])
```

If you want case insensitivity, you can import `Data.Char` and change `S.delete` to `(S.delete . toLower)`.

Comment: I do not understand the code. Why is there no mention of the string parameter anywhere?

Comment: @LouisCloete If you prefer, you can inline the definition of `(.)`; this gives `isPangram s = S.null (foldr S.delete (S.fromList ['a'..'z']) s)`.

Comment: I think I need to study the language on a much more basic level. I didn't understand what `.` does. I'm just going to waste your time otherwise.

Comment: @LouisCloete - Say if you define function f3 by: `f3 x = f2 (f1 x)`, this can be rendered in common math notation by: `f3 = f2 ∘ f1` , that is, you get f3 by *composing* f1 and f2. Note that in the last equation, there is no longer a variable name. Because of the ancient habit of sticking to ASCII characters for operators, in Haskell the function composition operator is just the regular dot `.` instead of ∘ as in mathematical litterature, so you have:  `f3 = f2 . f1`. Elimination of the variable name is known in Haskell parlance as eta-reduction or η-reduction.

Comment: @jpmarinier yes, I realized that after the previous comment. But I needed to ask the question first, so I just realized I first need to study a little about the basics of the language before wasting people's time on SO.

Answer (score 3):

This is based on Daniel Wagner's answer, but it finishes early if all the letters are found, whereas his walks the whole list, then works backwards deleting elements, then gives an answer when it gets back to the beginning.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Data.Set (Set)

letters :: Set Char
letters = S.fromList ['a'..'z']

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram xs0 = go xs0 letters
  where
    go :: String -> Set Char -> Bool
    go [] letters = S.null letters
    go (c : cs) letters =
      S.null letters || go cs (S.delete c letters)
```

You may be wondering why I match on the string first and check on `letters` under the match, instead of the other way around. Well, that's only because it's fun to rewrite this using `foldr`:

```
isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram xs0 = foldr step S.null xs0 letters
  where
    step :: String -> Set Char -> Bool
    step c r letters =
      S.null letters || r (S.delete c letters)
```

---

For something like the alphabet, `Data.Set` is not actually the most efficient way. It's better to use something like `IntSet`, which is much more compact and significantly faster.

```
import qualified Data.IntSet as S
import Data.IntSet (IntSet)

letters :: IntSet
letters = S.fromList (map fromEnum ['a'..'z'])

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram xs0 = foldr step S.null xs0 letters
  where
    step :: String -> IntSet -> Bool
    step c r letters =
      S.null letters || r (S.delete (fromEnum c) letters)
```

Comment: `any S.null . scanl (flip S.delete) allLetters` does the same short-circuiting without quite as much custom recursion. I would expect GHC to be able to fuse this away to be as efficient, though I didn't test that hypothesis.

Comment: Your comment about `IntSet` makes me wonder whether treating an `Int` like a 64-bit-long bitset (of which we only need 26) is worth it.

Comment: @DanielWagner, you may very well be right about that scan. I find `scanl` just a little bit wrong, so I've never really taken the time to learn to use it effectively. I predict that the bitset will be very slightly better. I believe the `IntSet` will basically be a bitset, since it's so small and contiguous, but it won't be unboxed and it'll have some redundant tests.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you are trying to check whether a string is a pangram, meaning it contains all the [insert your preferred language] alphabet.

The following code uses `Data.Set`. A set data structure can't contain duplicate elements by definition. We use this property of a set to count the number of elements that are in it after we added all the character from the string to it. If it's equal to the number of the alphabet we are working with, it means that the string contains all the characters of the alphabet, so it's a pangram.

Note that this code does not take care of the difference between lower and upper case letters and also counts white space and punctuation. This would give you wrong answers if there are any of these cases. With some tweaking you can make it work though.

The time complexity of this solution is `n * log 26` which is just `n` in Big O, as Daniel Wagner pointed out. The reason is that while Haskell's default set is a balanced tree, the number of elements in the set never goes above 26, so it becomes linear. Using a hashing implementation of the set may result in some optimization for very large strings. The space complexity is constant since the additional space we are using never exceeds 26 characters.

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as S

isPangram :: [Char] -> Bool
isPangram s = length (S.fromList s) == 26
```

Comment: You said that this ignores case, if you do S.fromList "aAbc" what is returned? Does it convert everything to lowercase?

Comment: After fixing up the "handles characters outside the range a-z", even the existing code that uses a balanced tree is O(n).

Comment: no, it does not. it counts "aA" as two characters. You need to convert all the chars to lower or upper if you care to not double count.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're probably right, but I have to go now. I'll look at it when I come back. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally,

```
allPresent :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
allPresent alphabet xs = foldr (\a r -> elem a xs && r) True alphabet
```

is a concise and inefficient code that will call `elem` as many times as there are letters in your `alphabet` and will "AND" the results.

For example, for a three-letter alphabet `a`, `b`, and `c`, it will be equivalent to an `&&`-chain of three calls to `elem` and a `True`:

```
allPresent [a, b, c] xs
==
elem a xs && elem b xs && elem c xs && True
```

It will stop as soon as the first missing letter will be detected, returning `False`. But it will potentially comb through the whole of `xs` anew for each letter of the `alphabet`, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are infact looking for a pangram, you could try this solution which I came up with.

```
import Data.Char ( toLower )

isPangram :: String -> Bool
isPangram text = all isInText ['a'..'z'] where
    isInText x = x `elem` map toLower text
```